# How to open a web browser when my windows service starts?

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows service that needs to automatically open a web page when it starts

This is what ive tried

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "")

2nd

Process.start()

Both these options work when you debug but they do not physically open the webbrowser when running the service

Comment: Where should the service open a webbrowser? The service itself has no desktop.

Comment: local machine, where the service is running

Comment: @user743414 local machine, where the service is running

Comment: And which logged on user should see opened browser and when exactly should the browser be opened?

Comment: Depending on what needs to happen with the data from the web server, you might be able to use the [WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @user743414. so my service picks up a URL on start up so i need to open the web browser automatically i.e dim strURL as string = "Http://google.com" process.start(strURL) so i need to apply the same logic but using the windows service i have created

Comment: @user743414 so anyone that is currently logged in on the machine can see the page

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is what i have tried   Dim strURL As String = "http://google.com)

   Dim request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl)
   Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
   Dim s As Stream = DirectCast(response.GetResponseStream(), Stream)

Comment: @Percy It sounds like what you need to do is set a startup program ([Change which apps run automatically at startup in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps)) or set a scheduled task for user logon [How do I create a scheduled task that will run as the logged in user](https://serverfault.com/questions/777710/how-do-i-create-a-scheduled-task-that-will-run-as-the-logged-in-user). Have you discounted those options?

Comment: @AndrewMorton maybe im not detail enough- i want to open a  browser and navigate to a URL using a windows service. all my service does is, it picks up a number then it should add it to the URL address open browser then navigate

Comment: @Percy Does it *have* to be a WIndows service? You would need to write a separate program which runs under the user's account and interacts with the service. In this case, it appears to me that that separate program could do everything without needing a service. [Interacting with a User from a Service Indirectly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Services/interactive-services#interacting-with-a-user-from-a-service-indirectly).

Comment: When your service starts, _no one_ will be logged on to the machine because services start before anyone logs on.  So back to @user743414 question, who should see the web browser?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the service is installed on one machine so doent really matter who sees it.

Comment: You're missing the point.  Since the windows service starts before anyone has logged on, _no one_ will see it because there is no desktop on which the browser will appear!

Comment: windows has "interactive" and non-interactive sessions...the windows service is in a non-interactive session.  This session has no interface and is not in any way tied to the person who is logging in (even if its running with the same user account)...no GUI...means no GUI browser...that said you can launch a web request without a browser and read its contents

Comment: @Ctznkane525 makes sense i get it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used c.method = "POST" and it worked